# What's the meaning of "by string of" in logic

Tags: meaning

I don't know the meaning of "by string of" in following sentence

> **Infer *by string* of IF-THEN statements**

found in the following

[image]
<sub>Source: [Knowledge Management in the Intelligence Enterprise](http://books.google.nl/books?id=6kK4VfF619oC&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=%22Knowledge+Management+in+the+Intelligence+Enterprise%22+infer+by+string&source=bl&ots=4fFdt2ZoQD&sig=LdOf2XTmKHcYhzVSo2G92ngPLEs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qRRFVNnVC4zsaOqpgYgB&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22Knowledge%20Management%20in%20the%20Intelligence%20Enterprise%22%20infer%20by%20string&f=false)</sub>

Comment: We neither unless you wrap it in more text - see my edits

Comment: Literally it means: by a sequence/series of...

Comment: *A* should be inserted before 'string', and 'by' could equally be 'using'.

Answer (score 2):

The string in your case is a series/sequence of if/then's resulting in a (shortcut) conclusion.

[String](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/string)

> 1. a series of things arranged in or as if in a line `<a string of cars>` `<a string of names>`
> 2. a sequence of like items (as bits, characters, or words)

<sub>source: [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/string)</sub>